# How to save buildings at specific coordinates in python?

Tags: python, random, coordinates

So I do know how to save the class's x,y coordinates but I don't know how to save buildings at the coordinates my player has been at. I'll attempt to make this more clear.

I'm making a text-based. To move your player you either type left,right,up,or down. It will therefore change your x and y accordingly.

Ex: To move up it adds 1 to the y value of the player class. player.yPos += 1 . However if the player goes to the point 0,1 and then 0,2 but moves back down to 0,1 and there was a building at the point 0,1 how do I make sure it's still there when the player goes back? I've been thinking I'll have to store all of the player's x,y movements in to a list. I don't know how to make the positions of that list equal the object that will be there though. If this doesn't make sense I can attempt rewording.

P.S. Please use the most simple logical explanation possible. Generally when I read something on stackoverflow I want to jump off of a cliff with how involved it is. (Basically, dumb it down for me please!)

```
class player:
    Cnuts = 0
    statPoints = 0
    pStrength = 0
    pConstitution = 0
    pQuickness = 0
    pIntelligence = 0
    pStamina = 0
    playerName = ''
    Weapon = 0
    Armour = 0
    Shield = 0
    inventory = []
    xPos = 0
    yPos = 0

#Building Code

class Entity:
    id = 0
    xPos = 0
    yPos = 0
    name = ''
    description = ''
    def __init__(self, id, xLocation, yLocation, name, description):
        self.xLocation = xLocation
        self.yLocation = yLocation
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

class Structure(Entity):
    pass
```

I haven't decided what goes in to the Structure/Building class because I don't know what else it needs other than what Entity already has. I have another class for monsters that also inherits from Entity which is why I have it.

```
#Map code

isExploring = True
def Map():
    while isExploring == True:
        pInput = input('What direction would you like to go?')
        if pInput == 'Up':
            player.yPos += 1
        elif pInput == 'Down':
            player.yPos -= 1
        elif pInput == 'Left':
            player.xPos -= 1
        elif pInput == 'Right':
            player.xPos += 1
        elif pInput == 'Diagonal Left':
            player.xPos
            player.yPos
        elif pInput == 'Diagonal Right':
            pass
        elif pInput == 'Down Diag Left':
            pass
        elif pInput == 'Down Diag Right':
            pass
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you not storing the location of the buildings anywhere?  There should be *some* kind of data structure that remembers where all the buildings are!

Comment: Some code examples would help.  How is your building data stored?

Comment: You can create a `dict` which uses `tuples` as `keys`, each `tuple`/`key` representing a coordinate. This way you can put whatever you need or want at each coordinate. So something like `{(0,1): buildingObj, (0,2): None, (0,3): someOtherObj}`, etc.

Comment: Why wouldn't the building still be there when the player goes back? How are you storing the location of things like buildings? Seems like that should be some sort of separate data structure holding them all, independent of the players' locations which change on every move they make.

Comment: @mattm Ok, but how would I access the keys if the characters goes on to those points because I have no idea if the player will go back to an exact point or what's there. It's different every time the game is run.

Comment: @martineau just uploaded the code. The buildings save it in their class.

Comment: From the code you've added, two things are apparent: One is that you don't understand the purpose of classes (and the difference between one and an instance of one). I suggest you study this more before anything else. There's some information on them in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=inheritance#a-first-look-at-classes) and many tutorial available on the web and in books. The second thing is that you have _no_ data structure representing the environment or world in which the game take place. <continued in next comment>

Comment: ...This could be something a simple as a list of instances of Buildings, Structure, and even Monsters, plus one of the Player class. Each one of these would have a x, y location, that in the case of a Player or Monster instance could change from move-to-move. However the location of a Building class instance probably would not, so if a Player instance's location was ever the same as building's, your program can easily detect that, regards of how many moves the player might have made.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see code for a building, but I'm guessing the building will eventually inherit from `Entity` (Player should also inherit this class). An entity object has `self.xLocation` and `self.yLocation`, so this makes it a bit easier to implement a location aware player. So what you do is that the class you make for building has to implement the `__hash__` method, so something like this.

```
class Building(Entity):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self.xLocatioin, self.yLocation))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Building) and hash(self) == hash(other)
```

The function is called `__hash__` because python recognizes this special keyword as meaning that the building object can be placed in a dictionary. So whenever you try to place a `Building` object in a set or use it as a key for a dictionary, python will automatically call it's `__hash__` method, and use that value to determine the position in which to place the object in the set/dictionary. Implementing hash usually means implementing `__eq__` which is another magic function that python automatically calls when you compare 2 objects using the `==` operator.

The player class will then store each building it has visited in a set, which can then be queried to determine if a building has been visited before

```
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super.__init__(self, args)
        self.visited = set()
        self.currLocation = tuple(self.xLocatioin, self.yLocation)

    def visit(self, entity):
        if not beenHere(entity):
            self.visited.add(entity)
        self.currLocation = tuple(entity.xLocatioin, entity.yLocation)

    def beenHere(self, entity):
        return entity in self.visited
```

And there you have it, now the player object can determine which building it has visited before or not